# Extracting subset of pandas dataframe based on months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the foll. pandas dataframe (df with a datetime index):

```
datetime    Year    cal val
1/1/2000    2000    1   0.23
1/2/2000    2000    1   0.34
2/3/2000    2000    1   0.45
4/4/2000    2000    2   0.56
4/5/2000    2000    2   0.67
4/6/2000    2000    2   0.78
5/7/2000    2000    3   0.89
7/8/2000    2000    3   1
7/9/2000    2000    3   1.11
```

How can I extract those rows which correspond to months from a list:

```
list_months = [1, 2]
```

Resulting dataframe will be:

```
datetime    Year    cal val
1/1/2000    2000    1   0.23
1/2/2000    2000    1   0.34
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
[x for x in df if df.index.month in list_months]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print df[df.index.to_series().dt.month.isin(list_months)]
            Year  cal   val
datetime                   
2000-01-01  2000    1  0.23
2000-02-01  2000    1  0.34
```

Comment: Probably better to access `index.to_datetime` then `index.to_series.dt`: Time comparison: `In [151]: %timeit df.index.to_datetime().month
10000 loops, best of 3: 83.3 us per loop`    

`In [152]: %timeit df.index.to_series().dt
1000 loops, best of 3: 377 us per loop`. So almost 4 times faster

Comment: But index is `datetimeindex`, I need `dt` because `dt.month` and `df[df.index.dt.month.isin(list_months)]` or `df[df.index.month.isin(list_months)]` doesnt work.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. `to_datetime.month` doesn't have `isin` method.